# Getting variables in flume.conf

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have a flume agent declared in a flume.con file.
Source is RabbitMQ, although this is not so relevant.
The thing is that I need to take out the credentials from there to another file.
I saw that the way to do that is in flume-env.sh, where I put this:

```
export RABBIT_USER=user1
```

And in the flume.conf I'm trying to get the value in this way:

```
agent1.sources.rabbitmq-source1.user = $RABBIT_USER
```

But when I run the agent, the variable is not substituted by its value, previously set in flume-env.sh and therefore, the agent doesn't connect to Rabbit.

`export RABBIT_USER=user1`  sentence is working, since if I echo the variable in the flume-ng script, the value  user1 appears on the console properly.

I tried several ways to access the variable from flume.con

with curly braces, $ within the curly braces, $ out....

No way.

Is there a way to get the variables inside the flume.conf properly?
I did lot of tests and investigation on the internet without results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable support is added in the 1.8 version. But it requires to set up a special property running an agent instance

```
flume-ng agent  --conf conf/ -f ./conf/flume.conf -n a1  -DpropertiesImplementation=org.apache.flume.node.EnvVarResolverProperties
```

Reference: